# How Do I Have "\printbibliography" use the same title style (spacing, margin, font, etc) as my ACKNOWLEDGEMENT section?

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, biber

I have browsed all possible relevant questions to no avail. Basically, I want there to be more space under the title "BIBLIOGRAPHY" in the same style as in "ACKNOWLEDGEMENT". No idea how that's possible.

```latex
\listfiles
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[style=numeric,sorting=none]{biblatex}
\bibliography{references}

\usepackage[intoc]{nomencl}
\textwidth=6in \oddsidemargin=0.5in \topmargin=-0.5in
\textheight=9in  % 9in must include page numbers
\textfloatsep = 0.4in \addtocontents{toc}{\vspace{0.4in} \hfill
Page\endgraf} \addtocontents{lof}{\vspace{0.2in} \hspace{0.13in} \
Figure\hfill Page\endgraf} \addtocontents{lot}{\vspace{0.2in}
\hspace{0.13in} \ Table\hfill Page\endgraf}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[left=1.5in,right=1in,top=1in,bottom=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
 \usepackage{amsfonts}
 \usepackage{amsmath}
 \usepackage{amsbsy,bm}
 \usepackage{amssymb}
 \usepackage{setspace}
 \usepackage{rotating}
 \usepackage{float}
 \usepackage{stmaryrd}
 \usepackage{multirow}
 \usepackage{color}
 \usepackage{soul}
 \usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{eepic}
\usepackage{colortbl}
% \usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage[mathscr]{euscript}
\usepackage[titletoc,title]{appendix}
\usepackage[titletoc]{appendix}
\usepackage[tocgraduated]{tocstyle}

\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{amssymb, amsmath}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[subfigure, titles]{tocloft}
\usepackage{acronym}
\usepackage{datetime}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algorithmic}

\renewcommand{\nomname}{LIST OF ABBREVIATIONS}
\makenomenclature
\graphicspath{{./figures/}}
\DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.pdf,.jpeg,.png,.PNG, .eps, .tiff}

\urlstyle{same}

\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage{appendix}
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{7}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{7}


%new chapter/section and subsection commands
\newcommand{\hsuchapter}[1]{\chapter*{#1} \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{#1} }
\newcommand{\hsusection}[1]{\section*{#1} \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{#1} }
\newcommand{\hsusubsection}[1]{\subsection*{#1} \addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{#1} }

%%%%%%%Configure Table of Contents%%%%%%%%%%%%
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{TABLE OF CONTENTS}
\renewcommand{\cftchapfont}{\normalfont}
\renewcommand{\cftchappagefont}{\normalfont}
\renewcommand{\cftchapleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}}

%%%%%%%Configure List of Figures%%%%%%%%%%%%
\renewcommand{\listfigurename}{LIST OF FIGURES}
\setlength{\cftbeforefigskip}{0.2in}

%%%%%%%Configure List of Tables%%%%%%%%%%%%
\renewcommand{\listtablename}{LIST OF TABLES}
\setlength{\cftbeforetabskip}{0.2in}

%%%%%%%Configure Bibliography%%%%%%%%%%%%
% \renewcommand{\bibname}{ \texorpdfstring{{BIBLIOGRAPHY\vspace{10mm}}}{BIBLIOGRAPHY}   }

%%%%%%%Configure Chapter Headings%%%%%%%%%%%%
\makeatletter
\def\@makechapterhead#1{%
%  \vspace*{50\p@}%
  {\parindent \z@ \centering
    \normalfont
    \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
      \if@mainmatter
        \@chapapp\space \thechapter
        \par\nobreak
        \vskip 20\p@
      \fi
    \fi
    \interlinepenalty\@M
    #1\par\nobreak
    \vskip 40\p@
  }}
\def\@schapter#1{\if@twocolumn
                   \@topnewpage[\@makeschapterhead{#1}]%
                 \else
                   \@makeschapterhead{#1}%
                   \@afterheading
                 \fi}
\def\@makeschapterhead#1{%
 % \vspace*{-10\p@}%
  {\parindent \z@ \centering
    \normalfont
    \interlinepenalty\@M
    #1\par\nobreak
    \vskip 10\p@
  }}


%%%%%%%Configure Section Headings%%%%%%%%%%%%
\renewcommand\section{\@startsection {section}{1}{\z@}%
                                   {-3.5ex \@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
                                   {2.3ex \@plus.2ex}%
                                   {\centering\normalfont}}

%%%%%%%Configure Sub-Section Headings%%%%%%%%%%%%
\renewcommand\subsection{\@startsection {subsection}{2}{\z@}%
                                   {-3.5ex \@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
                                   {2.3ex \@plus.2ex}%
                                   {\noindent \normalfont  }}

%%%%%%%Sub-Sub-Section's Not  Supported%%%%%%%%%%%%

%%%%%%%Configure Table of Contents Heading%%%%%%%%%%%%
\renewcommand{\@cftmaketoctitle}{
  \chapter*{\contentsname}
  \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{TABLE OF CONTENTS}}

%%%%%%%Configure List of Figures Heading%%%%%%%%%%%%
\renewcommand{\@cftmakeloftitle}{
  \chapter*{\listfigurename}
  Figure \hfill Page
  \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{LIST OF FIGURES} }

%%%%%%%Configure List of Tables Heading%%%%%%%%%%%%
\renewcommand{\@cftmakelottitle}{
  \chapter*{\listtablename}
   Table \hfill Page
   \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{LIST OF TABLES} }

\makeatother

\setcounter{section}{-1}

% Define new commands here
\newcommand{\etal}{\emph{et al.}}
\newcommand{\leftsup}[2]{{\vphantom{#2}}^{#1}{#2}}
\newcommand{\leftsub}[2]{{\vphantom{#2}}_{#1}{#2}}
\newcommand{\leftsupsub}[3]{{\vphantom{#3}}^{#1}_{#2}{#3}}

\DeclareMathOperator*{\assembly}{\textbf{\Large A} }

\definecolor{lightblue}{rgb}{.90,.95,1}
\newcommand{\hllb}[1]{
    \sethlcolor{lightblue}
    \hl{#1}
    \sethlcolor{yellow}
    }

\newcommand{\hlc}[2][yellow]{{\sethlcolor{#1}\hl{#2}} }

 % Define floats here
 \floatstyle{plain}
 \newfloat{Box}{h}{lob}
 \newcommand{\boxedtext}[3]{
    \begin{Box} \caption{\small{#1}}
    \hspace{1.cm}
    \fbox{\begin{minipage}[c]{0.85\linewidth}

    \small{#2}

       \end{minipage}}

       \label{#3}
       \end{Box}
  }

 \begin{document}



%\pagestyle{myheadings} \markright{\today}

\pagenumbering{alph}

\begin{titlepage}
\thispagestyle{empty}\enlargethispage{\the\footskip}%
\begin{center}
    {\setstretch{1.66} {Noise Suppression in Ultrasound Beamforming\\ Using Convolutional Neural Networks}\par }%
    \vskip.4in
    By
    \vskip .3in
    {Zhanwen Chen}
    \vskip .3in

    \begin{doublespace}
    Thesis\\
        Submitted to the Faculty of the \\
        Graduate School of Vanderbilt University \\
        in partial fulfillment of the requirements \\
        for the degree of \\ [.1in]
    \end{doublespace}

    \MakeUppercase{MASTER OF SCIENCE} \\[.1in]
    in \\[.1in]
    {Computer Science} \\[.25in]
    December 14, 2019 \\[.25in]
    Nashville, Tennessee
    \vskip .5in
\end{center}
%%%Uncomment for Signatures%%%
% Approved: \hskip 2.9in Date:\\[1.2em]
% \rule{3.5in}{.5pt} \hskip 0.1in \rule{2in}{.5pt} \\[.01in]
% [Committee Chair]\\[.14in]
% \rule{3.5in}{.5pt} \hskip 0.1in \rule{2in}{.5pt}  \\[.01in]
% [Committee Chair]\\[.14in]
% \rule{3.5in}{.5pt} \hskip 0.1in \rule{2in}{.5pt} \\[.01in]
% [Committee Chair]\\[.14in]
% \rule{3.5in}{.5pt} \hskip 0.1in \rule{2in}{.5pt} \\[.01in]
% [Committee Chair]\\[.14in]
%\\[.14in]
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%Uncomment  for Approved Names%%%%%%
\begin{center}
\begin{doublespace}
Approved:\\
Matthew Berger, Ph.D. \\
Maithilee Kunda, Ph.D.
\end{doublespace}
\end{center}
\end{titlepage}

\doublespacing
\pagenumbering{roman} \setcounter{page}{2}

\chapter*{To my parents, Cheng Yuehong and Chen Feng. Thank you for years of unconditional support and encouragement.}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{DEDICATION}
\vspace{7mm}

\chapter*{ACKNOWLEDGMENTS}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{ACKNOWLEDGMENTS}
\vspace{7mm}
I want to thank my PI, Dr. Brett Byram for giving me my first research opportunity through which I have grown as a researcher for the last year and a half. I want to acknowledge our post-doc, Dr. Adam Luchies whose thorough explanations of the data and methods made everything possible. I also want to thank my colleagues in the BEAM lab, Chris Khan, Katie Ozgun, Dr. Jaime Tierney, Dr. Kazuyuki Dei, Siegfried Schlunk, Emelina Vienneau, and Abbie Weeks for tirelessly explaining the basics of ultrasound and a variety of related work.

I want to thank my thesis advisor, Dr. Matthew Berger for teasing apart problems, giving insight, and posing critical questions that inspire scientific thinking in a computer scientist. In addition, it would be difficult to conduct the various important experiments without the serious computing power he has generously shared.

I also want to thank my Computer Science PI, Dr. Maithilee Kunda, for advising me since the very beginning of my masters career. She has drilled in me important lessons on how to be a researcher.
\tableofcontents

\listoftables
\newpage
\listoffigures
\newpage


\normalsize
\doublespacing
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\setcounter{page}{1}



\include{chap1}
\include{chap2}
\include{chap3}
\include{chap4}
\include{chap5}
\include{chap6}

\printbibliography[title={BIBLIOGRAPHY}]
% \printbibliography


% \defbibheading{secbib}[\bibname]{%
%   \section*{#1}%
%   \markboth{#1}{#1}}
%
%
% \printbibliography[heading=secbib]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please remove from your example code all the stuff (e.g., many packages and macros) that are not relevant to your question. All we really need is something that produces the two divisions whose headings you are concerned about.

Comment: If "Acknowledgements" is a chapter heading followed by 7mm of vspace, make "Bibliography" (or your `\bibname`) a chapter heading followed by 7mm of vspace: `\documentclass{book}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{book1,
title={A title},
auth={A Uthor},
year={}
}
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\begin{document}
x\cite{book1}
\chapter*{ACKNOWLEDGMENTS}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{ACKNOWLEDGMENTS}
\vspace{7mm}
Text
 \defbibheading{bibliography}{%
  \chapter*{#1}%
 \markboth{#1}{#1}\vspace{7mm}}
\printbibliography
\end{document}`